# Double clicking the title bar of iTunes 11 does not minimize the window

Tags: itunes

With Mac applications I can double click on the title bar of the application and then it will minimize. iTunes 11 lost this behaviour.

Is there a way to restore it?

I'm on OSX 10.6.8 and using iTunes 11.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been an annoying feature of iTunes 11. Other internet forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4554172?start=0&tstart=0) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20542580?tstart=0#20542580?tstart=0), are already discussing the issue and as yet are without a solution. Imagine it's something that needs to be implemented by apple.

Answer (score -1):

Leave the mouse in the top right corner of the iTunes frame, your file bar should drop down with a little blue indicator showing two caddie cornered arrows pointing into each each other.

If this won't work, unplug your mini-display port, three finger slide left to access maximized docks and try it again.

Comment: The two arrows don't minimise iTunes, they take the app out of fullscreen mode. What do you mean by `access maximized docks`?